# Using AsyncUpload on mobile device (Galaxy SII)

Tags: mobile, browser, upload, telerik

**EDIT :**
This morning i've test it with iphone 4 and its working perfectly so its probably specific on Android (i'm using Version 4.1.2) Vs AsyncUpload Control

I am currently creating a file upload section on a web page that can be view on every type of device (Computer, Tablets and mobile phone). When i test the file upload section on a standard computer everything works perfectly. When i test it on mobile phone (I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2 with all the latest update) i have access to the files on my phone. I can select the file that i want and it seems to upload perfectly ( I got the green dot from the telerik control which means that the upload has been successful ) but in fact the file created in the template directory of the control ( app_data\RadUploadTemp ) has a size of 0 bytes. So when i press my submit button, the file copied in my working directory is invalid and cannot be read. You can test it yourself on a telerik demo page.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/additionalfields/defaultcs.aspx

When i upload a file on this page from my mobile phone, the file size is always 0... So from there i know that its not something with my code but its something between the control and the mobile browser.

I have asked my question on telerik forum but i didn't get any answer yet.

Does someone know if there is a limitation from mobile browser to upload file using RadAsyncUpload control

And by the way, RadAsyncUpload control use the html5 File API first, if the browser cannot use it, the control will try to use flash/silverlight. if its still not working, it will use standard IFrame module to upload the file.
Here are some docs about the control http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-overview.html

I would like to know if someone else can test it on the demo page and let me know if it works. If not , anyone have an alternative solution to upload file from mobile phone ?

Thanks !

Sebastien

Comment: Ok here is the solution i got from Telerik Staff.

This is a known issue that seems to come from the Android's browser itself. We found that problem logged in their tracking system - 1 and 2. In order to workaround that problem please add the following lines of code before the declaration of the RadAsyncUpload. Disabling - FileApi, Silverlight and Flash modules the control will upload the selected files at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to solve the problem on Android. i was not able to put it in my comment.

Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.Flash.isAvailable = function () { return false; };
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.FileApi.isAvailable = function() {return false; };
    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAsyncUpload.Modules.Silverlight.isAvailable = function() {return false; };

I just added a kind of If (android) do the code

Cheers !